# Edit text issue in Nexus 7

Tags: android, nexus-7

I add a edit text in my layout and set it's adjust pan property in manifest. It works fine in every phone except in `Nexus 7`. In `Nexus 7` it covers my edit text. Is there any way to handle this problem in `Nexus 7`?

Comment: It is not suitable question for stack overflow as per guideline. You should ask this in user experience section of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used gravity attribute to your edit text.? Or to the container holding the edit text. If yes remove gravity attribute and check it once.